# JAX-WS disable WSDL publishing

Tags: web-services, tomcat, wsdl, jax-ws, wildfly

I'm searching for a way to disable the WSDL publishing (?wsdl). Both Endpoint.publish and the container (Tomcat or Wildfly) should be stopped publishing the wsdl. I found a way to disable the status page on Tomcat/Wildfly via `com.sun.xml.ws.server.http.publishStatusPage` but no way to disable the wsdl. The property `com.sun.xml.ws.server.http.publishWSDL` doesnt work.

How can i disable the publishing of the wsdl?

best regards,

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: because its a security issue if its deployed in production.

Comment: Only if you are using "security by obscurity" and enforced transport level encryption. You could simply block this url on your loadbalancer if you really wanted to hide

Comment: @fr3ak4l it seems this property `com.sun.xml.ws.server.http.publishWSDL` was never taken into account, in contrary to the other one `com.sun.xml.ws.server.http.publishStatusPage` which is used to set the flag `boolean publishStatusPage` from `com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this by adding a new WSDLFilter to my own security filter chain. If someone is interessted in the filter, please contact me.